# How do I debug with PyCharm while using Vagrant

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, vagrant

I am new to Python. I am new to Vagrant. However, my team runs their project using a Vagrant VM and IDEs of their own choosing. I chose PyCharm, because I've used some JetBrains products in the past.

I'd really like to be able to visually debug through it as it is running. Set a break point, view the values of variables, etc.

PyCharm has a help section (and the related articles above it):
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-product-to-work-on-the-vm.html

I've done all of them, but under Project->Project Interpreter the Path Mappings seem to list all the shared folders on the between the host machine and the Vagrant VM. Those shared folders are

1. one directory up from the actual project
2. my vagrant directory
3. My home directory

I don't think it is pointing to the project or its dependency libraries correctly.

I also get a yellow message at the bottom that says Python packaging tools not found.

If I hit debug, I get the following output in a terminal:

```
bash: line 0: cd: /vagrant/app: No such file or directory
pydev debugger: process 2032 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.6183.50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in 
<module>
    main()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/vagrant/app/__main__.py'
```

It also has opened itself a tab for 'pydev.py' that has in it:

```
Remote file /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py is mapped to the 
local path C:\Users\<my username>\vagrant\.pycharm_helpers\pydev\pydevd.py 
and can't be found. You can continue debugging, but without the source. To 
fix that you can do one of the following:
```

How can setup to debug from PyCharm on my host machine through code running on the Vagrant VM?